# Magento: How do I pass data to a child layout block?

Tags: php, magento, layout

in product/view.phtml, I have the call getChildHtml('my_block') ?>, which outputs a phtml file I wrote. I want that file to display the product image, but when I call $this->getProduct(), I get null! How do I pass the product (or any other data) to a child block? Or otherwise make it available?

Comment: Please provide information about your block. What kind of block is it? How did you create it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are currently on a product display page I would suggest using the current product registry value. This can be loaded instead of your $this->getProduct() as follows:

```
Mage::registry('current_product');
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need! Although, I am still curious if there is a general method for passing data to a child block - or is this "registry" the only way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options this has its own setProduct and getProduct function. But what does your block extend?

Comment: I don't actually know. I just added a <block> entry to the layout xml with a template in it, I didn't write a php class for it. So, whatever the default is, I suppose.